# auto_increment al tope mariadb

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, mariadb, backend, sequelize.js

Estoy creando un sistema de información [fincareport.com](https://fincareport.com) y una de mis dudas que me tiene algo pensativo es que pasa con las tablas donde tenga la columna id con **auto_increment** de typo Int llegue a su maximo valor. En caso de que cambie el tipo Int por BigInt que pasa si tambien llegase al maximo valor.

¿Como reutilizar los id eliminados?, es decir como hacer para que los ids (2,3,4) los vuelva a tomar el auto_increment y no continue con el 6 hasta que use (2,3,4). Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te  recomiendo re-utilizar ID eliminados, tendrás todo un trabajo adicional para eliminar todos los ROWS hijos y en cascada, puede ocasionar inconsistencia y confución, inclusive no debes borrar como medida de seguridad, usa eliminado lógico.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el tope para un INT en mariadb es de 2147483648, esos son realmente muchos registros asi que no creo que llegues a necesitar tantos.
De todas formas si fuera a producirse el caso en el cual ese dia viniera, la base de datos te daria un error `Error Code: 167. Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1`
 podes hacer una contrastacion empirica por tu cuenta con el siguiente SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    val CHAR(1)
);

ALTER TABLE t AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483648;


INSERT INTO t(val) VALUE('a');
```

Una solucion para la reutilizacion de ids puede ser reasignar los ids, ir registro por registro dandole un id nuevo a cada uno y luego resetear el auto_incremente al valor del ultimo id que hayas recreado. Aunque puede volverse engorroso si esa tabla tiene muchas relaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Podrías utilizar [BITINT UNSIGNED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html) que su tope es 18446744073709551615, por otro lado configura tu herramienta de monitorización y alertas para que te envíe una alerta cuando llegue hasta cierto porcentaje y así no te agarra desprevenido y tendrás tiempo de actuar.
2. Defines el [PRIMARY KEY que use UUID](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/guiduuid-performance/). No te lo recomiendo.

Agota primero la opción BITINT UNSIGNED que te dará mucho tiempo de vida.